# In a C# solution, Where do you declare solution-scope enums?

Tags: c#, enums, projects-and-solutions

In a C# solution, Where do you declare solution-scope enums ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to declare them within a Project which all other projects in the solution reference.

Comment: The Class Library project type, and the same answer also applies to all other language features aside from enums.